# Gumbel Distribution on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, probability

I know the parameters `mu` and `alpha` for Gumbel distribution that are 5.08 and 1.02, respectively. But `evpdf(x,mu,sigma)` function in Matlab takes `mu` and `alpha` as its parameters. How do I plot the probability distribution function for Gumbel distribution using the parameters that I have?

On [this](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/evpdf.html?searchHighlight=evpdf) page, it's not clearly stated what exactly is `sigma`. If I find the standard deviation using `mu = 5.08` and `alpha = 1.02`, even then I don't get the right curve.

[image]

Comment: I don't know that distribution but maybe you can derive `sigma` from the [following](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GumbelDistribution.html) formulae?

Comment: Tried using the same formula. I have mentioned that in the last line of the question. It still doesn't give me the right distribution function.

Comment: Well that was not clear to me that you used that formula.

Comment: What is `alpha`? Anyway, on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) you have formulae for converting among parameters of that distribution

Comment: Have you tried using [`copulapdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/copulapdf.html) e.g. `copulapdf('gumbel',mu,alpha)`? However I would suspect, based on the documentation page you link to, that for `evpdf` the `sigma` parameter is your `alpha` and `X` is a vector of values that you want the PDF evaluated at

Comment: `alpha` is basically reciprocal of `beta` (given on Wikipedia). This `alpha` notation is given in the book that I am studying from. Well, I have tried those formulae, it doesn't yield the right plot.

Comment: Could you please check the image that I have attached now?

Comment: There are Gumbel maxima and minima distributions as well, you should clarify which one you need, the formula from the book would settle this.
The meaning of `sigma` [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/extreme-value-distribution.html)
@Dan I would not go with copulas as those are for multivariate distributions, unnecessary complication.

Comment: @Arpi unfortunately, that's all they have stated in the research paper (check the image). I checked it too that there are two types of Gumbel distributions. I tried bott though and the pdf I require matches none.